# Models not working with db.collection.insert via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I started with the very basics and the .save function where i use my models to autogenerate a unique id as well as the an auto generated timestamp, everything was fine.

then i tried to save an entire array to the database and this is the query i ended up wi

```
    let instagram = new Instagram();
let data = req.body.url.split('\n');
let dataArray = [];
data.forEach(datum => {
    split1 = datum.replace('https://www.instagram.com/', '');
    split2 = split1.replace('/', '');
    time = Date.now;
    var datetime = new Date();
    dataArray.push({
        igurl: datum,
        igid: split2,
        owner: req.user._id,
        cdate: time,
        status: "New"
        });
});

instagram.collection.insert(dataArray, function(err,docs){
    if(err){
        req.flash('danger', 'error = ' + err);
        res.redirect('/instagram/add');
    } else {

        req.flash('success', 'IG URL has been added');
        res.redirect('/instagram');
    }
    });
});
```

the problem is that uid is never generated while using the .collection.insert function because i think the model is never invoked or is overridden in this scenario...

how do i bulk insert via the normal model route so that my model defaults can be triggered.

Comment: `Instagram.collection.insert()` or better yet just `Instagram.create()` Using `new Instagram()` creates a `Document` **instance**, where the imported `Instagram` is the actual "model".

Comment: @NeilLunn instagram is used in two ways one with a small i and one with a capital I.

Comment: Exactly. You want the "capital I" one. That's the "model", and the "small i" is an "instance".

Comment: @NeilLunn so while using the model itself and not the instance it would trigger my model defaults?

Comment: @NeilLunn this worked like a charm thank you so much for the help!!!! im still learning so every bit helps.

Comment: Yes. But not with anything `.collection` since that is directly using the underlying driver. You can read all of this in the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Model)